# How to I get the parent property's class type after using GetProperties to get a list of properties on a class?

Tags: vb.net, propertyinfo, getproperties, bindingflags

I'm using GetProperties to get a list of properties for a class.

```
Dim properties As List(Of PropertyInfo) = objType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public).ToList()
For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
    'how do I get the parent class type of the prop (level up in hierarchy from property's ReflectedType)?
Next
```

How do I get the parent class's one level up of the current property's `ReflectedType`? Note that this class could have multiple parent levels. I don't want the `BaseType` of the current property's class, but simply the next level up in the hierarchy of the property's `ReflectedType` as a property could be several layers deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try an approach like this - basically a loop walking up the inheritance tree...

```
Public Function WalkInheritanceFromProperty(pi As PropertyInfo) As List(Of Type)
   Dim currentType As Type = pi.ReflectedType
   Dim parentType As Type
   Dim lst As New List(Of Type)

   Do
      parentType = currentType.BaseType
      If Not parentType Is Nothing Then lst.Add(parentType) Else Exit Do
      currentType = parentType
   Loop While Not parentType Is Nothing
   Return lst
End Function
```

Here is some info that may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx